# SSIS - Unable to submit package in 32 Bits

Tags: ssis, x86, odbc, sql-server-2014

I have developed a SSIS package which uses a 32 bit ODBC driver to connect to our legacy systems.  I can run the package from Visual Studio, using Run65BitRunTime = False and it runs fine.  However, when I deploy the package to the SSISDB catalogue on our SQL2014 box and select 'Run in 32 bits' from the Advanced tab of the config options I get the following error:

[image: Run in 32 bits]

[image: The path for 'ISServerExec.exe' cannot be found]

I have found quite a few posts describing this error but as yet failed to find a solution.  One [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0c3accf-fde7-4d0c-9e8c-6dfaf3aa6bdb/executing-a-package-in-32bit-mode-the-path-for-isserverexecexe-cannot-be-found-error?forum=sqlintegrationservices) suggests checking the registry setting for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SSIS\Setup\DTSPath`.

For this we found it was pointing to ProgramFiles and not ProgramFiles (x86), which is where the exe resides.  However changing this setting and restarting the services and server did not fix the issue.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.